# Pull request on GitHub contains other commits from my colleagues

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I'm working with a team and we're using GitHub.

Let say I setup two remote repositories as follows:

- upstream: this is the centralized repository for the whole team.
- origin: this is the forked repository from upstream.

All of these repositories have the branch *'develop'* which is used for development. I work on local branch *'develop'* which will be pushed to origin/develop later.

Following is the commands I issues before creating a pull request. Note that I checked out to local *'develop'* at that time.

```
$git commit

$git pull --rebase=preserve upstream develop

$git push
To https://github.com/lamhohs/some_repo.git
 ! [rejected]            develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/lamhohs/some_repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

$ git pull --rebase=preserve origin develop

$ git push
```

The last push command was successful. Then I created a pull request from *origin/develop* to *upstream/develop*. However, in GitHub, the pull request showed other commits from my colleagues. It made the reviewer hardly to review the changes I made.

**My question is: How can I create a cleaner pull request?**

---

My solution is that instead of calling `'git pull --rebase=preserve upstream develop'`, I called `'git pull'` as follows:

```
$ git pull upstream develop
$ git push
```

Nevertheless, the pull request also contained a merge commit from *upstream/develop* into local *'develop'*.

Comment: The cleaner way is to do all the changes on a feature branch and use pull requests to modify the develop branch.

Comment: @choroba: Could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

2 Solutions:

1. Perform your code review by SHA. Whatever system you are using MUST support some kind of SHA selection for your codereview. Type:

   ```
   gitk&
   ```

   Locate the SHAs for your commits. Upload those SHAs to your code review and it will show only the changes from those commits.
2. Make sure your change is the last change. These are some steps to turn all your commits into 1 commit, that is the most recent on your branch.

   ```
   git branch -m "mydevelop"

   git pull

   git checkout develop

   git merge --squash mydevelop develop

   git commit -m "my changes as one commit"
   ```

   As choroba has said, you should not be using your development branch with the same name for you work. You should pull it, rename it, do your work on the renamed branch and then when you are ready to merge with development, that is when you merge it back to develop.
   If you keep making your changes directly to the develop branch then your going to run into a lot more trouble in the future if you don't have a good understanding of git.

Comment: @tyler-s-loeper
Here is the error I encountered:
`$ git checkout develop
`error: pathspec 'develop' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Here is the current branches:
`$ git branch


  master
* mydevelop`